# Operate on vector elements of a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to perform vector operations on elements of a data table.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is a toy example:

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(V1 = list(c(1,2),c(1,2,3)), V2 = list(c(1,3),c(2,2,1)))
> dt
      V1    V2
1:   1,2   1,3
2: 1,2,3 2,2,1
```

I can achieve the results I want with a loop:

```
> for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
+   dt$diff[i] <- sum(abs(dt$V1[i][[1]]-dt$V2[i][[1]]))
+ }
> dt
      V1    V2 diff
1:   1,2   1,3    1
2: 1,2,3 2,2,1    3
```

This is obviously ugly and slow.  I can't figure out how to do this in data.table.  My best attempt is this:

```
> dt[,diff := sum(abs(V1[[1]]-V2[[1]]))]
> dt
      V1    V2 diff
1:   1,2   1,3    1
2: 1,2,3 2,2,1    1
```

Comment: Analysis on list columns is only an option if you don't care about speed.  Maybe try using `longDT = dt[, lapply(.SD, unlist), by=.(r = 1:nrow(dt))]` instead.

Comment: I cant see how unlisting the vectors to a long format data table would solve this.  row #2 is 3=abs(1-2)+abs(2-2)+abs(3-1).  how do you sum the elements with different length vectors from long format?

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. `longDT = dt[, lapply(.SD, unlist), by=.(r = 1:nrow(dt))][,diff := abs(V1-V2)][,sum := sum(diff), by = r]`  gets me pretty close.  Now I just need to figure out how to pull `sum` from `longDT` into `dt` by the row numbers.  any ideas?   I tried this `dt[,row := .I][,diff := longDT[r == row,sum]]`  but it's bad syntax.

Comment: Yup. I'd go long `df[, r := .I]; longDT = dt[, lapply(.SD, unlist), by=r][, diff := abs(V1-V2)]`; aggregate `rdt = longDT[, .(diff = sum(diff)), by = r]`; and then if it is needed in `dt`, use an update join `dt[rdt, on=.(r), diff := i.diff]`. (I didn't test this code.)